# SDL Event Queue

Tags: c++, event-handling, sdl, keyboard-events

I have the following code which 
is part of some function which moves a dot on the screen.
I am using SDL

```
if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){

    //BreakPoint A

    if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_d){
            goLeft = true;
            //BreakPoint B
        }
    else if(event.type == SDL_KEYUP)
        if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_d){
            goLeft = false;
            //BreakPoint C
        }
    else{
         //BreakPoint D
    }

}

//BreakPoint E

//Move sprites and other things..
//Update  screen ..
```

All of this is in a loop.Each time this loop is ran, calculations are being made for the moving of the dot and a frame is rendered.
My problem is that when I continuously press 'D' , after leaving the button the dot
doesn’t stop immediately.

Changing `if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){`
to `while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){`
things are Ok.Why is this happening?

One assumption is that that by pressing 'D' continuously the event queue is being flood by keyboard input events.So many of these events are being inserted in the event queue and all of this happens in one frame of rendering or one iteration of the loop I said above, but on each frame I remove only one event from the queue.So when i leave the 'D' button no more events are inserted and the "extra" moving happens because to get the event that the 'D' has been released and update the goLeft variable I must first remove all those events that were flooding the queue one by one.So until those are being released the dot will move.

But from the other side if I have the `while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){` and 'D' is continuously pressed will it ever leave this inner loop ? Because this loop is ran while there are events in the queue and as I said I continuously insert them by pressing 'D'.

**EDIT**

As I said with the while loop it works fine and it actually escapes from the loop.How does it happen?
And from some tests that I have done I saw that when pressing 'D' continuously the program executes on each external loop iteration as follows :

- BreakPoint A
- BreakPoint B
- BreakPoint A
- BreakPoint C
- BreakPoint E

Answer (score 1):

I thin I just answered a similar problem: [SDL mouse events are not being handled quick enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620780/sdl-mouse-events-are-not-being-handled-quick-enough/20624481#20624481)

It seems you are experiencing the same issue, namely waiting for vsync in the middle of your event loop. If you are expecting events to fire continuously, you can do something like:

```
Uint32 timeout = SDL_GetTicks() + 10;
while(SDL_PollEvent(&events) && !SDL_TICKS_PASSED(SDL_GetTicks(), timeout)) {...}
```

That will ensure that your event loop does not run for more than 10ms.Or you could have a counter and make sure you don't run for more than "x" iterations.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer.
Actually what happens is that it escapes the loop.Because as I said it works fine with the while loop.
And one part of my question is why and how this happens.

Comment: It escapes the while loop because even if you have a high keyboard repetition rate you'd be getting a new key event at most every hundred milliseconds or so (10 key events per second, but I think it's typically a much lower rate). In the meantime, the queue is mostly empty (give or take a few mouse events), so the while loop ends. If you instead remove events one by one using "if" (versus "while"), it's possible that a bunch of events accumulate while you are rendering, giving that "delayed movement" effect you see when you stop pressing the key.

Comment: Can you explain why that rate is low?
Does the SDL do it intentionally is it from the operating system?

Comment: I don't think SDL touches the repetition rate, it's an OS setting. From a quick Google search it seems it maxes out at about 30 keys per second, depending on OS and keyboard type. That's one event every 33ms, plenty of time for your loop to escape the "while" condition.