# SDL mouse events are not being handled quick enough

Tags: c++, events, mouse, sdl

I've been playing around with SDL for a few days now, and while I think I got the hang of it, I've run into a small problem with the menu. More specifically, the buttons in the menu. They work flawlessly when the mouse isn't moving that fast, but when I speed it up a bit (moving the cursor between the buttons, constantly making the button redraw from "normal" sprite to "mouse-over sprite"), it lags behind, sometimes doesn't update at all and small bugs start appearing.

This is all my code regarding the management of buttons and events in general:

```
while(!Exit)
{
while(SDL_PollEvent(&Ev))
    {

        curTime = SDL_GetTicks();
        if((ControlVar == 1 && Ev.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION) || (ControlVar == 1 && Ev.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) || (ControlVar == 1 && Ev.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP)) {
            But1.doAction();
            But2.doAction();
            But3.doAction();

                if(curTime > lastTime + 25) {
                SDL_RenderClear(Screen);
                ApplyImage("Menu.png");

                But1.Draw();
                But2.Draw();
                But3.Draw();

                SDL_RenderPresent(Screen);
                lastTime = SDL_GetTicks();
            }

        }

        if(Ev.type == SDL_QUIT)
            Exit = true;
    }
SDL_Delay(10);
}
```

And:

```
class Button {
int Id;
int Clip;
SDL_Rect box;
std::string Filepath;

public:

    Button::Button(int number, int X, int Y, std::string filename)
    {
    Id = number;
    Clip = 0;
    box.x = X;
    box.y = Y;
    box.w = 300;
    box.h = 40;

    Filepath = filename;
    }

    void Draw()
    {
    SDL_Texture *tex = nullptr;
    SDL_Rect targetRec;
    tex = IMG_LoadTexture(Screen, Filepath.c_str());
    targetRec.h = 40;
    targetRec.w = 300;
    targetRec.x = 0;
    targetRec.y = Clip * 40;

    SDL_RenderCopy(Screen, tex, &targetRec, &box);

    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
    }

    void doAction()
    {
        if(Ev.motion.x > box.x && Ev.motion.x < box.x+box.w && Ev.motion.y > box.y && Ev.motion.y < box.y+box.h)
        {
            if(Ev.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION && Clip != 2)
                Clip = 1;

            if(Ev.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN && Ev.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                Clip = 2;

            if(Ev.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP && Ev.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                Clip = 1;
        }
        else if(Clip != 0)
            Clip = 0;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Try moving `SDL_RenderPresent(Screen);` outside of the `while(SDL_PollEvent(&Ev))` loop. By calling SDL_RenderPresent like that you are likely polling only 60 events per second (one per frame if vsync is enabled), causing the delay you see.
If you move SDL_RenderPresent outside of your event loop, you'll be able to process as many events are there are available in the queue, and when you are done you present the frame and wait for vsync.

Comment: Did what you said and it didn't help much. After some experimenting I believe that this is a problem of MouseMotions simply not being recorded accurately enough by the event handler.

(Lets say I move my mouse 50 pixels on the X axis, instead of updating 50 times it updates say three times, one time when its at 10, another time when at 35 and finally one more time when at 50.)

Been trying to come up with a way around this but so far I havn't thought of anything.

Comment: Up, I'm curious too because I'm in the same case some years after. If you found anything to improve it ^^